# Turning oil into solid for candles

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I added stearic acid to hot vegetable oil and saw it turned to a sludgy, slush material in about 1.5 hours. Is there any other natural additive that I can add to make it more solid in the same amount of time?

I'm currently trying soy wax + stearic acid.

Are there any other natural alternatives?

Comment: i think hydrogenation is basically what im doing here, but I cant seem to find a way to strengthen the bonds beyond a slush. I dont have access to any heavy equipment

Comment: For hydrogenation you need to add hydrogen. Hydrogen _gas_. And then some.

Comment: And you need to describe your experiment better. What temperature, approximately? Still hot after 1.5h? What vegetable oil? Plus: what gave you the idea stearic acid could solidify oil? What are you trying to achieve? As is, I vote to close, an answer requires too much speculation.

Comment: What you did and especially what you want to do is totally unclear. Turn something into solid means, in everyday context, a lot of things. In chemistry almost nothing. So hard to say. Unless you want a margarine or a soap.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think hydrogenation is at play in here. More likely you just get chunks of solid in liquid, thus sludge. Otherwise you would get more smooth material.

Similar processes that can make more solid-like material are gellatine and agar-agar, that make gel that holds everything, emulgators like egg that help to hold different materials together by making small droplets.

You could be expecting this process to happen, but stearic acid is already a result of this process, and you dont seem to add NaOH:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saponification